# SVN command line in jenkins fails due to server certificate mismatch

Tags: svn, jenkins

When I run the svn command line from the Jenkins shell I get this error:

```
 D:\Jenkins\jobs\Merge Trunk to Stable\workspace\stable>svn up --trust-server-cert --non-interactive 
 Updating '.':
 svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://xxx/stable'
 svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://xxx/stable': Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname,  issuer is not trusted (https://xxx)
```

But when I run the same from the command line CMD window it is OK:

```
 D:\Jenkins\jobs\Merge Trunk to Stable\workspace\stable>svn up
 Updating '.':
 At revision 1797.
```

or

```
 D:\Jenkins\jobs\Merge Trunk to Stable\workspace\stable>svn up --trust-server-cert --non-interactive
 Updating '.':
 At revision 1797.
```

Any idea how to solve this??

Comment: do you need to add somewhere the server fingerprints for that server?

Comment: Not that I know of. I don't actually understand the question... I know the server certificate name is not matched. It caused me no problem before.

Comment: I had in mind something like in Tortoise/Network/Subversion server file ; there might be a missing setting there, but that's just a guess.

Comment: it is not a tortoise SVN client, it is collabnet's CLI client.

Comment: Can you run it with the `--verbose` flag in each case to get some more info? But like @fduff says, it sounds like some configuration (either in a file or environment variable) is different between the two.

Comment: I did some investigation: Jenkins runs as windows service thus the profile sets the APPDATA to another place. Since the svn cli puts there (at svn.ssl.server folder) the signatures both cases read the different folder. I copied the files and the error now came to authentication error. (I also copied the simple folder).... but I guess there is some security check that simply copy the cache file is not enough.

Comment: Basically I need to run once and accept manually from the Jenkins environment. anyone know how I can get interactive shell from Jenkins environment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pretty old question, but still quite alive.

As you know, the problem is that the accepted certificate cache (as well as the username/password cache) is per-user, and since Jenkins is running as a different user (most likely SYSTEM), it has no idea of your regular user cache.

Not all SVN clients let you do the "echo p" thing there (it didn't work for me), and the `--trust-server-cert` apparently doesn't work in this case either.

What worked for me was to [open a console window as SYSTEM](https://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/22/getting-a-cmd-prompt-as-system-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008.aspx), and do the interactive acceptcertificate-login-password dance in there.

Since all of this is cached, you only need to do this once, and from then on, all `svn up` and similar requests will work.

Comment: plusone - Three years later, still an issue and your answer saved me!  Thx.

Comment: In the windows service itself, change the "Log On" from system to an user. If that user can use svn in command, so should the service. This is what I did to fix the issue (similar to running svn as system first, but doesn't feel like a hack)

Answer (score 8):

I finally managed to solve the problem! What I did is simply put in Jenkins script:

```
echo p | svn up --username <usr> --password <pwrd>
```

This solved it! since the echo emulated the manual input to accept permanently the certificate.

Root Cause is the fact that Jenkins shell scripts run under the windows service user - thus uses a different place for the user profile cache (in `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Subversion` instead of `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\`)

Comment: What do you mean you "put in a Jenkins script", where did you create/place the script file?

Answer (score 1):

`echo p | svn commands`

Worked great in Jenkins windows batch command prompt. Doing this once will permanently accept the certificate for the Jenkins user in the Build box.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen even you had accept the certificate.

In Linux, Jenkins use its own username. You can use command `sudo su jenkins` switch to jenkins user , then use command `cd ~` and  `ls` to see the jenkins user's root path. For me, it is the jenkins install path (var/lib/jenkins).

You can see `.subversion` package in your user package. If you had accept the certificate before, you can see `auth` package in .subversion.

Copy the whole `.subversion` package to the jenkins install package(jenkins user's root path).

Try it again, use `svn up` command in jenkins shell and it would work.

My English is poor, thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the certificate is issued to a different hostname (not xxx, but something like xxx.yourcompany.com). If yes, then do a clean checkout with this hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Running Svn commands through Jenkins on slave was giving me difficulty. I did the following:

If you are on unix then follow this link: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_subversion_to_trust_a_given_ssl_certificate.html

If you are on Windows then do:

```
cd %APPDATA%\Subversion\
```

Then edit the `server` file in that directory by removing the `#` sign from the `ssl-authority-files` element and update the path to where you stored your ssl certificate file.

Also change the following, if you like it to store your credentials.

```
store-passwords = yes 
store-ssl-client-cert-pp = yes
```

Once that is done, you would also need to add the certificate to your windows machine by following [Add the Cert to the Trusted Root CA Store](http://www.systemroot.ca/2014/09/git-stash-set-up-self-signed-ssl-certificate-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a horrible answer but after exhausting the other ones, which didn't work for me due to other issues, I choose to go the route of changing the SVN server to not use SSL.

This was only an option because I just setup this server and it's on a totally internal network, but it did eliminate the issue entirely. And I ran out of other options and time.

I also only suggest this incase someone doesn't realize it is even an option. Using SSL would make me feel much better regardless of the server exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with Jenkins and Window 7 .
I solved this by go into services and select Jenkins and go to Log-on and enter the administrative credentials and restart the jenkins service.

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: How did restarting the service solve your problem?  What did you change before doing the restart?