# SVN SSL Certificate Untrusted via Python Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, svn

I have a strange scenario going on at the moment. When I issue an `svn info TXN REPO` command on our build server (separate from the SVN server), it works as expected and displays the relevant information to the console.

However when I script it using Python, and specifically, Popen from the subprocess module, it prints a message `svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate untrusted` to the standard error (console).

What I've tried:

Using `--non-interactive` and `--trust-server-cert` flags within the script call.

Passing a username/password within the `svn info` call via the script.

The above two don't seem to take effect, and the same error as above is spat out. However, manually running the same command from the command prompt succeeds with no problems. I assume it might be something to do with python opening up a new session to the SVN server, and that session isn't a "trusted" connection? But I can't be sure.

Our SVN server is on a windows machine and is version 1.8.0

Our build server is a windows machine running Jenkins version 2.84. Jenkins executes a batch script which kicks off the Python script, performing the above task.

Command: `svn_session = Popen("svn info --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --no-auth-cache -r %s %s" % (TXN, REPOS), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)`

** Edit **

When I copy and paste the python line from the script into the interactive python shell on the same server, the command works as expected also. So the issue is how the script is executing the command, rather than the command itself or how Python runs that command.
**

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is looking at this in the future. Panda Pajama has given a detailed answer to this..

[SVN command line in jenkins fails due to server certificate mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951546/svn-command-line-in-jenkins-fails-due-to-server-certificate-mismatch)